# KeyboardInterrupt behaves differently on different executions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used this block of code to interrupt function execution without any error tracebacks.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nKeypress Detected. Exiting...\n')
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    exit(0)
```

It works when I run the script directly but when I install the package by running my `setup.py` installer and run it that way, I still get traceback messages. What am I missing here?

Traceback:

```
 File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\Scripts\yts-scraper-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('YTS-Scraper==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'yts-scraper')()
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\yts_scraper-0.2-py3.7.egg\ytsscraper\main.py", line 77, in main
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\yts_scraper-0.2-py3.7.egg\ytsscraper\scraper.py", line 184, in download
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\yts_scraper-0.2-py3.7.egg\ytsscraper\scraper.py", line 112, in __initialize_download
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\yts_scraper-0.2-py3.7.egg\ytsscraper\scraper.py", line 126, in __filter_torrents
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3-1.25.6-py3.7.egg\urllib3\response.py", line 560, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3-1.25.6-py3.7.egg\urllib3\response.py", line 752, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3-1.25.6-py3.7.egg\urllib3\response.py", line 682, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Compilers\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: It's not really clear how the code you posted is related to a `setup.py`, but if you have `if __name__ == "__main__":` the code won't be run if it's not in the main module anymore.  If you run `setup.py` then it's now the `__main__` module.  Otherwise I don't think I could say anything without you being more specific about what you're doing...

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I understand now that you're using a console_scripts entry-point.  Nevertheless, the same admonition applies: The wrapper script generated by setuptools is now the `__main__` module and not your module.  Try moving the exception handling directly into your `main()` function instead; maybe refactor a bit if you need to.

Comment: Yes, I used entry point. I now see what I was doing now. Entry point calls main function directly instead of executing the whole script so try except block cant get executed. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you so much! I will post the solution now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The wrapper script generated by setuptools is now the **main** module and not your module. Try moving the exception handling directly into your main() function instead; maybe refactor a bit if you need to. – Iguananaut

As mentioned in this [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008254/keyboardinterrupt-behaves-differently-on-different-executions?noredirect=1#comment106127049_60008254), `setup.py` entry point calls the `main()` function directly and the exception handling was out of the function. So, running the function with package name after the setup results in calling the `main()` function, not the whole `main.py` script, which executes the `main()` function inside the exception handler thus works fine.

Refactoring the code like this solved the issue:

```
def main():
    try:
      #do stuff here
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nKeypress Detected. Exiting...\n')
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    exit(0)
```